# Passing array of structures and 2d array to a function using c++/vC++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, visual-c++, character-arrays

I need Help  in this i have an  Struct

```
typedef struct {  
    unsigned char data0; 
    unsigned char data1; 
   //  like this 8 bytes of data in my structure 
} MyStruct;

typedef struct {
    Mystruct my_st[8];
} Info1;

typedef struct { 
    unsigned char My_Array[8][7];
} Info2;

//now i want to pass the  array of 8 structures in Info1 and 2D array of Info2 .
My_Function( &Info1->my_st[8], &Info2->My_Array[8][7]);
```

is this correct way or else please let me know .

Comment: `My_Function( &Info1, &Info2);`? This passes the structs to My_Function. The definition of `MyStruct` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype should be

```
void My_Function(MyStruct (&my_st)[8], unsigned char (&My_Array)[8][7]);
```

and call it that way:

```
Info1 info1;
Info2 info2;
My_Function(info1.my_st, info2.My_Array);
```

But it would be simpler to have:

```
void My_Function(Info1 &info1, Info2 &info2);
```

and

```
Info1 info1;
Info2 info2;
My_Function(info1, info2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char data0;
    unsigned char data1;
    //  like this 8 bytes of data in my structure 
} MyStruct;

typedef struct {
    MyStruct my_st[8];
} Info1;

typedef struct {
    unsigned char My_Array[8][7];
} Info2;

//declare My_Function
void My_Function(MyStruct[], unsigned char[][7]);


int main()
{
    Info1 i;
    Info2 j;
    // use My_Function
    My_Function(i.my_st,j.My_Array);
}
```